# Filling fields in an observable, with results from another observable in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I've got two requests.

`/users` and `/user/<id>/milpac`

`/users` results an `User[]` observable, while `/user/<id>/milpac` results an milpac object.

```
export class User {
  join_date: string;
  promotion_date: string;
  user_id: number;
  username: string;
  milpac: Milpac;
}

export class Milpac {

  user_id: number;
  milpac_id: number;
  real_name: string;
  username: string;
  rank: string;
  rank_shorthand: string;
  status: string;
  primary_position: string;
  bio: string;
  join_date: string;
  promotion_date: string;
}
```

First I retrieved all the users with:

```
getAll(): Observable<User[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.API_AUTH_HEADER
    });
    const options = { headers: headers };
    return this.http.get<UserResult>(this.API_URL + '/users/active', options).pipe(map(r => r.data.users));
  }
```

Then, after a while, it became a requirement to load a milpac into an User:

```
getMilpac(userId: number): Observable<Milpac> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.API_AUTH_HEADER
    });
    const options = { headers: headers };
    return this.http.get<MilpacResult>(this.API_URL + `/user/${userId}/milpac`, options).pipe(map(r => r.data));
  }
```

My objective now is to somehow load a `Milpac` into an `User` object, by using an `User` object, and ultimately emit this in the observable stream.

The result of the observable should stay `User[]` but have filled in fields of `Milpac` per `User`.

**I know that mergeMap etc functions exist, I just can't seem to get them to work. Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction?**

Comment: Of course you can solve this within the Angular application. But it doesn't make much sense to iterate over all the users and then request additional data one by one. I'd solve this problem in your server-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned - this should be done on the server. If you anyways need to do it on the client you can do it like this:

1. Use `Array.from` to split up your users so you get one at a time
2. `mergeMap` each user with it's account balance and immediately pipe the result to the user
3. Call `toArray` to get your users back as an array

I've created a simplified showcase here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6mivga

Note that this only works if your stream is completing (as otherwise the toArray would never emit). If this is not the case it get's a bit more complicated but the mechanism stays the same.

Comment: Please put the code within your answer. Should stackblitz no longer be available in the future, this answer loses part of its value :-).

Comment: Thanks! Will probably fix this on server, will check out your example as well.